# Truly disable Bluetooth computer's discovery in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, bluetooth

What am I missing in the below picture?

[image]

Why my computer is discoverable with *Allow Bluetooth devices to find this PC* unchecked (confirmed that this is what is actually happening)?

What should I do to *truly* disable discovery of my computer via Bluetooth in Windows 10? Is this possible at all (any other way than turning Bluetooth off)?

Comment: The PC is probably in connectable state (which is automatically turns discoverable mode also).

Comment: Thanks. I don't know what is "connectable state" and I don't know, if my PC is or isn't in it. I don't know how to enable it and if I enabled it. All I know, is that if I enable Bluetooth (usually turned off in my case) then my PC is discoverable by all nearby Bluetooth devices even with mentioned checkbox obviously unchecked. Which seems to be a non-sense. This problem occurs for all my PCs with Windows 10 and equipped with Bluetooth, not just for a particular device.

Comment: Copnnectable state means that Bluetooth device can accept connections. To do that it must also be discoverable (discoverable state). On early Windows versions there were 2 checkboxes: "Aloow to discover" and "Allow to connect". I do not know why the second one was removed in Win 10. However you can control the sates programmatically using BluetoothEnableDiscovery() and BluetoothEnableIncomingConnections() functions.

Comment: Thanks, but... this is users-related site, not Stack Overflow. So functions- and coding-related solution wouldn't fit me. The idea with this question is to find out, if I can have Bluetooth enabled without my device being BT-discoverable by other devices? And, if yes, then how to achieve it. At user interface- and user-level. Without coding. For me, executing some PowerShell script is top, what I can do.

Comment: Powershell call to winapi, not programming: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/use-powershell-to-interact-with-the-windows-api-part-1/

Comment: https://github.com/btframework/DiscCtrl

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are 2 states of the local Bluetooth Radio:

- **Connectable** state means that Bluetooth device can accept connections.
- **Discoverable** state allows other devices to discover your one.

In early Windows versions there were 2 checkboxes: "Allow to discover.." and "Allow to connect..". I do not know why the second one was removed in Windows 10.

However you can control the sates programmatically using BluetoothEnableDiscovery() and BluetoothEnableIncomingConnections() functions.

As you asked to do that without programming you can call the functions from PowerShell (here is the link describes how to call WinAPI from PowerShell: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/use-powershell-to-interact-with-the-windows-api-part-1/)

Or I wrote very simple console application that switches the Bluetooth Radio states. You can find its source code and compiled exe by this link: https://github.com/btframework/DiscCtrl

Comment: Thank you for a comprehensive answer and preparing mentioned program. I have already accepted your answer. However, I cannot verify if your program is working correctly, because Microsoft Windows Defender [is preventing me from running it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q7wcW.png). Also, please note that the checkbox in question is not removed from Windows 10 (it is visible in my question's screenshot), it is only not working / is ignored by Windows 10.

Comment: It is removed. There how it looks on Win 7 and 8: https://www.dummies.com/wp-content/uploads/147631.image2.jpg

Comment: You can build the app from source or simple allow to run it by defender. Unfortunately I can not sign the exe file.

Comment: Look at a screenshot that is placed in my question. At image in this question. Right sight of it. "Bluetooth Settings" Control Panel applet is _not_ removed from my Windows 10 and I can clearly _see_ "Allow Bluetooth devices to find this PC" checkbox. My screenshot, taken in Windows 10, is actually a 1:1 duplicate of the screenshot you attached in your comment above. So the checkbox is still there and it is not removed from Windows 10. Only it is ignored / meaningless as PC is still discoverable, even with this checkbox unchecked.

Comment: Look at the image I posted: there are 2 check boxes. |Aloow to connect" and "Allow to discover". To make your device non-discoverable you must uncheck both. On your image there is just one check box.

Comment: No, I see your point. Yes, you are correct. However, I was referring more like to the first checkbox in first (top) frame. That controls whether your device is discoverable or not.

Answer (score 3):

The question is based somewhat on misunderstanding. The *Allow Bluetooth devices to find this PC* is not ignored. As per design<sup>1</sup> (a feature, not a bug in Windows 10) given PC is Bluetooth-discoverable when:

- mentioned *Settings* app page is opened / visible,
- mentioned *Bluetooth Settings* window is visible.

When both are closed, Bluetooth discoverability should be turned off automatically (and your PC shouldn't be discoverable by any other device) even though Bluetooth is still enabled and you can pair any device with your PC.

If, for any reason, this is not working as expected then refer to [Mike Petrichenko's answer](https://superuser.com/a/1606175/156554) above (the accepted one) for any possible solutions.

<sup>1</sup> <sub>Many systems, applications and solutions has something similar implemented. For example, in many Android-based devices and under many versions of Android system your device becomes Bluetooth-discoverable only when you are actually displaying Bluetooth section of Android settings. And discoverability of given device is turned of by default whenever you leave this screen to any other.</sub>

Comment: In fact no, it does not work so on Win 10. Probably that should, but does not. In fact, the old function (BluetoothEnableIncomingConnections and BluetoothEnableDiscovery) do not work on Win 10 as expected and as described in docs. Instead of that there is new undocumented function (BthpEnableConnectableAndDiscoverable) were added. However it also does not work as it should and sometime it must be called twice to set flags (states) correctly. IIn final this function sends IOCTL to BTH driver. WinRT UI does the same (sends IOCTL). But BTH driver does not process that IOCTL correctly.

Comment: I cannot provide you with technical / WinAPI details as I have no required knowledge. But from user perspective, here is what I can observe. When I am using Windows normally, I see "No nearby Bluetooth devices were found" on my mobile phone. When I open "Bluetooth & other devices" section of Settings in my Windows 10, my laptop becomes immediately discoverable by my mobile device. If I close that section, my mobile again reports no nearby devices. This is how it works when "Allow Bluetooth devices to find this PC" checkbox is unchecked.

Comment: When "Allow Bluetooth devices to find this PC" checkbox in "Bluetooth Settings" window (old Control Panel applet) is checked, my laptop is discoverable by my mobile device all the time, irrespective of whether I have corresponding Settings window open or not.

Comment: Both are absolutely correct behaviour. But sometimes Windows ignores the checkbox settings and stay discoverable always (as I described above - it is a Windows bug).

Answer (score 0):

I'm dont think there is an easy way to workaround the problem by user

BTW, the test method is not realiable

- `BluetoothEnableIncomingConnections` and `BluetoothEnableDiscovery` are designed for Classic Bluetooth
- Modern Android/iOS phones are designed for BluetoothLE

> That's really infuriating that the Win32 APIs are half-implemented
> -- [from a Microsoft MVP](https://github.com/timsneath/win32/issues/389#issuecomment-1079831432)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).